# Can the "Crusader Kings II Collection" be split?

Tags: steam, crusader-kings-2, humble-bundle

The "Crusader Kings II Collection", as bought **from The Humble Store**, is a single Steam key, or multiple keys that can be redeemed to multiple accounts?

I'm asking here because apparently they have a 5-day queue for support requests, but there's a discount lasting only 2 days.

Clarification: does **the Humble Store** give you "a single Steam key" for the whole bundle, or it gives you "multiple Steam keys"?

Answer (score 3):

I can't speak to Crusader Kings 2 specifically, but I have bought "complete" packs of games before, and any article you already have in your library will be sent to your inventory instead (so you can gift it to friends).

E.g. buying the complete XCOM pack activated all DLC in my library, but the base game was just added to my inventory since I already have it.

Steam seems to never allow you to activate something that already exists in your library, I've not encountered anything to contradict that so far.

**Edit** If you want to selectively split up the pack (not just what you already have in your library, but specific items) The single key translates to a pack on steam, which immediately activates everything (minus what you already have)

*However*, if you sent this pack to your inventory instead of your library, you can then choose which ones you activate.

Comment: Did you start from the Humble Store, or did you just start from Steam, in these cases? Because part of the question would be if they give a single or multiple keys in the first place. (still interesting, though)

Comment: Humble Store gives a Steam key. That key translates to an item on the Steam store. If it's more than a single game (which is the case here), it translates to a pack. Activating the pack activates everything (minus what you already have). Putting it in your inventory instead puts every item in the pack in your inventory, which you can then selectively activate.